# Illustrating coordinate graph by tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw the following figure by tikz but could not find a similar one:

How to draw this?
[image]

**Edit:**
In my test of @Zarko answer, where I use entire example except `[margin=3mm]{standalone}` I got the following result:

[image]

Comment: What you try so far?

Comment: I haven't done it so far. I'm seeking a similar template/outline of this figure.

Comment: This can be easily achieved using several `\draw` commands (for example `\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,3);`) and later placing some nodes for the labels and colored circles. There are a lot of examples on this site that you can use to create something to start with. We are happy to help you with concrete problems you come up with.

Comment: The Zrko's answer is OK for me even without `[margin=3mm]{standalone}`! Which version of TeXlive you are using?

Answer (score 4):

hm, if you would look in the "Ti*k*Z and PGF manual", at least some tutorial and "part III: Ti*k*Z ist kein Zeichenprogramm, than draw this simple diagram should not be a big problem ...

For starting point can serve the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

    \begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    dot/.style = {circle, fill=#1},
every node/.append style = {align=center},
          font = \sffamily
                        ]
\draw[-Straight Barb] (0,0) -- (8,0) node[right] {X};
\draw[-Straight Barb] (0,0) -- (0,7) node[above] {Y};

\draw[densely dashed, very thin] 
    (0,6) node[left] {S} -| (2,0) node[below] {Q}
          node[dot=gray, draw, pos=0.5, label=empty] (e) {} 
    (0,4) node[left] {P\\ ($0<\mathsf{P}<n$)} -- (4,4) node[dot=orange, label=below:B] (b) {}
                         -- (4,0) node[below] {R}
    (e) -| (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Missed part of diagram I left to you. You can do this on the same way as is shown for first two dots (circleS) diagram.

Comment: Thanks a  lot for your example. But the letters (e.g. empty, P, B, X) are gathered and overlapped on the zero point in my environment. Why?

Comment: @Sato, with my code or do you change something?  Image in answer is generated with showed code.

Comment: No, I use your entire example except [margin=3mm]{standalone}. My reproduction is added to the question.

Comment: @Sato, please, clarify, how you tested without `[margin=3mm]{standalone}`. Please, be so kind and to image in question add complete small document by which you tested my MWE (Minimal Working Example).

Comment: Oops, I made a small example of yours then it works. If I incorporate it into my research documents, overlapping letters appear... why?

Comment: I found it works well if I remove \usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}. Is it incompatible with your example?

Comment: @Sato, sorry, I haven0t crystal ball to see what you have in your document why you need option `dvipdfmx` at `graphicx` package. Modern/recent  version of package automatically select proper driver for proper work. Just remove this option. It is not needed (to my opinion, but I haven't any information about your document nor how you compile it).

Comment: All right. Thanks.